# soap_ssl_server_context without using pem file

Tags: ssl, openssl, gsoap, pem, hsm

I am using [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html) and it was compiled `WITH_OPENSSL`. I have found that there is only an API `soap_ssl_server_context` which takes as PEM file.

Is it possible to provide the private key to gSOAP layer without passing through the PEM files? i want to use [HSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module)

Comment: i want to use gsoap with HSM (Hardware Security Module)

Answer (score 1):

Typically for key management, an HSM e.g. a Thales Payshield 9000, will provide a public key in DER binary format (which can be converted to PEM format using binary->base64 conversion).

However, it is not really intended to provide you with the Private key in DER or PEM format. The private key will be encrypted with the HSM LMK (Local Machine Key).

This means that only HSM can translate the encrypted value (often a pin verification key) to another encryption key.  This really is the point of having an HSM e.g. PCI compliance for Visa or MasterCard. You are not meant to get the clear data in software.

If you need to decrypt the data yourself, perhaps just use a software solution like .net RSA or BouncyCastle.